# New Droid Incredibles, Having Some Annoying Problems

Tags: android

We've been developing an Android app at work for a few months now and recently acquired Droid Incredibles (API ver. 8) to replace our HTC Dev Phones (API ver. 4).

DANG are these some sweet new toys, but unsurprisingly, they've got a few quirks...

1)  It's normal for my user to let the program run for long periods without any input, but he'd still need the display to work the entire time.  Can anybody suggest a function call or setting or something that will prevent the Incredible's screen from dimming while my application is running??

2)  On the Dev phone, I was able to copy my application's database file (thousands of uses, that) onto the SD card's root directory and fly.  I could view the directory on my PC via USB; when I released the SD card from the PC, my application was perfectly happy with it and obediently read from and wrote to the database; and I didn't have to remove the SD card, ever.  That doesn't seem to be the case with the newer, better phone, though.  My application seems to be reading my start up parameters properly, but all attempts to save data in my database aren't working so well unless I'm just doing something wrong.  Can anybody point me to documentation specifically geared toward the Incredible??

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 1):

Use [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

Also request a permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The phone itself is not really the problem. Have you only targeted API version 4 until now while developing or have you actually tried API version 8 on an emulator too?

It just sounds as if you have to get the API v8 techniques right which in fact don't differ that much from the v4's.

The real difference regarding v4 and v8 is that the SDCards path changed (at least for me but I'm using a custom developer ROM so I can't really tell for sure if thats the case on a normal device) from /sdcard to /mnt/sdcard.

Comment: I had no API requirement previously (because my phones were API 1 and 4 and my emulator was API 8 -- the constant warnings from Ecplise were REALLY annoying and of no value).  Now that I'm using the Incredible, I added <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> to my manifest because it seemed harmless.  The path to the SD card DID change exactly as you describe (no problem there), but it also seems like I've lost write permissions (which kind of is a problem).  Any idea what I need to do to be allowed to write to my database file??

Comment: It would appear that my app doesn't have write permissions in the root directory of the SD card, but it does have write permissions in the directory I created.  (Isn't that writing?  Whatever...)